# Count the frequency of element of an array in C#

Tags: c#

I want to write a code in C#.

In fact, I want to write a program in C# such that the program receives a list of numbers and then receives another number and finally  check  how many times the received number occurs in the given list.

I searched and obtained the following code in C#  from GitHub.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Array9a
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, j,N,count;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Maximum Range for the Array");
            N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string[] a = new string[N];
            int[] freq = new int[N];
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                a[i] = Console.ReadLine();
               freq[i] = -1;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                count = 1;
                for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
                {
                    if (a[i] == a[j])
                    {
                        count++;
                        freq[j] = 0;
                    }


                }
                if (freq[i] != 0)
                {
                    freq[i] = count;
                }

            }
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
             {
                 if (freq[i] != 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}{1}", a[i], freq[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the  mentioned code is the  frequency  of all elements. But I want to modify the code such that the program receives a number and just check the frequency of the given number.

Recently I am learning C#. Thanks in advance

Comment: So do you just want to count how many times a given number occurs?

Comment: @John Yes. Just the program counts the frequency of a given number occurs.

Comment: It seems that you want your program to count all numbers?

Comment: Consider storing the data in a `Dictionary<int, int>` rather than an array.

Comment: @RoadRunner You right. In fact, I want to modify it such that just count the frequency of a given number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That seems pretty straight forward.

```
var result = freq.Count(x => x == theNumberToCheck);
```

Comment: @mjwills Maybe my question be simple. But I want to the program recevies a list of number such as [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5] and then the program asks to enter a number such as 5 and after that the the output of program be "the number 5 is 3 times". If it is possible please modfy the code and post it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: @user `freq` is your number array, `theNumberToCheck` is the number you've taken as input (and converted to the correct data type, e.g. int).

Answer (score 2):

Very simple you can use linq ,for example

```
        int frequency = 1;
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 4, 6, 7, 1, 2, 6 ,1};
        var res =arr.Count(x => x == frequency);
        Console.WriteLine(res);//print 3
```

Answer (score 2):

To get counts of every number:

```
var distinctValues = theList.Distinct().ToArray();

for(int i = 0; i < distinctValues.Length; i++)
{
  var cnt = theList.Count(e => e == distinctValues[i]);
  Console.WriteLine($"Element {distinctValues[i]}, count {cnt}");
}
```

Comment: or just a group by `var freqList = numbers.GroupBy(x => x) .Select(x => new { x.Key, count = x.Count() })`

Comment: @TheGeneral It depends on what result is desired :)